# how to resolve? error[E0422]: cannot find struct, variant or union type `LineColumn` in crate `proc_macro`

Tags: error, compile

```rs
error[E0422]: cannot find struct, variant or union type `LineColumn` in crate `proc_macro`
   --> /home/wangchao/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.ustc.edu.cn-61ef6e0cd06fb9b8/proc-macro2-1.0.56/src/wrapper.rs:476:33
    |
476 |                 let proc_macro::LineColumn { line, column } = s.start();
    |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^ not found in `proc_macro`
    |
help: consider importing this struct through its public re-export
    |
1   + use crate::LineColumn;
    |
help: if you import `LineColumn`, refer to it directly
    |
476 -                 let proc_macro::LineColumn { line, column } = s.start();
476 +                 let LineColumn { line, column } = s.start();
    |

error[E0422]: cannot find struct, variant or union type `LineColumn` in crate `proc_macro`
   --> /home/wangchao/.cargo/registry/src/mirrors.ustc.edu.cn-61ef6e0cd06fb9b8/proc-macro2-1.0.56/src/wrapper.rs:490:33
    |
490 |                 let proc_macro::LineColumn { line, column } = s.end();
    |                                 ^^^^^^^^^^ not found in `proc_macro`
    |
help: consider importing this struct through its public re-export
    |
1   + use crate::LineColumn;
    |
help: if you import `LineColumn`, refer to it directly
    |
490 -                 let proc_macro::LineColumn { line, column } = s.end();
490 +                 let LineColumn { line, column } = s.end();
    |
```

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue in my GitHub actions and not locally.

Updating my crates using `cargo update` seemed to fix the dependency that was causing this issue.

Perhaps give this a try!

Comment: Had the same issue, `cargo update -p "proc-macro2"` solved it.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that the `LineColumn` struct or variant cannot be found in the `proc_macro` crate. The suggested solution is to import the struct through its public re-export or refer to it directly.

Here's an example of how you can resolve the error by importing the `LineColumn` struct directly:

```rust
use proc_macro::LineColumn;

// Rest of your code
```

Alternatively, you can use destructuring assignment to extract the `line` and `column` fields directly without mentioning the struct's name:

```rust
let LineColumn { line, column } = s.start();
let LineColumn { line, column } = s.end();

// Rest of your code
```

By using either of these approaches, the `LineColumn` struct should be accessible in your code, resolving the compilation error.